# What is "timmy whinge" all about?

Tags: history, naming, scite

The [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) text editor has an option in its [configuration files](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html) called "tab.timmy.whinge.level".

What's the story behind this name?

As I understand it, "whinge" is a British-ism for "whine" -- Google [defines](http://www.google.com/search?q=whinge) it as "complain persistently and in a peevish or irritating way". So who exactly is Timmy, and what is he whining about? There's got to be a story there.

It's not really relevant to anything, but every time I see that option in the docs, I have to wonder.

Comment: I've never noticed that before, would be interesting to know though!

Comment: Looks likely to be a reference to Tim Peters, major Python contributor and author of the original tabnanny (amongst many other things!). I can't find anything authoritative, so I just leave it as a comment.

Comment: Just a suggest did u ever see Monty Python series , it was a british series there was a character called Tim with scottish who was a magician , wizard they call him Tim the enchanter

Comment: @Michael: Neil Hodgson confirmed your guess, so you can post it as answer with a reference to the recent thread in the SciTE interest mailing list...

Comment: @PhiLho I'm not seeing a relevant thread on the [Scite interest group](http://groups.google.com/group/scite-interest/topics) and searching it for whinge or timmy returns no matches. Is there another mailing list that I'm missing?

Comment: @Michael: sorry, the person posted to scintilla-interest even though it was about SciTE. Correct link is http://groups.google.com/group/scintilla-interest/browse_thread/thread/1ee6eea2d332d0ae

Comment: That person was me - I posted to Scintilla since the option exists there, and other editors based on it also have "tab timmy" options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the definitive source](http://groups.google.com/group/scintilla-interest/browse_thread/thread/1ee6eea2d332d0ae): Neil Hodgson, lead developer of Scintilla:

> I shouldn't have named a feature
>   after a real person.
>
> The standard Python module for
>   checking indentation is 
>   'lib/tabnanny.py' which was
>   implemented by Tim Peters.

Comment: I'm giving you the accepted answer, since you're the one who posted the question on the mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

It is a reference to Tim Peters, major Python contributor and author of the original tabnanny (amongst many other things!). Confirmed by Neil Hodgson on the [scintilla-interest mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/scintilla-interest/browse_thread/thread/1ee6eea2d332d0ae).

Comment: You beat me to transfering the answer here :( I want my 10 points! :p